# Zipcode DB Architecture in Rails with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have around 65000 zipcodes in my database table named 'Zipcode'. I also have a 'Deal' table and I want to fire queries based on zipcode. Please help me to architect in a right way as currently it is consuming too much time in firing query.

Comment: They have been associated with a third table but it take much time to insert 65000 records and fetching them.

Comment: can you share your queries and some sample data, database schema as well